# Communication is lost on wifi toggle and onDisconnect and onPeersDisconnected not being fired

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using code from Google's sample game "ButtonClicker2000" found here: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

I have 3 androids running this game in genymotion plus one on my own phone, debugging them all from android studio.  I've gotten to a point where I'm trying to gracefully handle disconnect in the event of network issues.  The way I'm simulating network issues is toggling the wifi on my phone.  (on or off, same behavior)  After that, real time messages from my phone are no longer being received by the virtual devices, and my phone is no longer receiving real time messages from the other devices.  However, my phone never enters onDisconnect() and the other devices never enter onPeersDisconnected.  If I exit the app on my phone after communication ceases, onPeerLeft fires on the other devices.

How can I either ensure communication between devices in a game isn't lost in the **likely** event that a user at some point comes in or out of range of their wifi?  If that's not possible, how can I at least ensure the onDisconnect event is firing from the offending device and onPeersDisconnected event is firing on the others?

Answer (score 2):

If we're going with what the documentation states, [`onDisconnect`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onDisconnected()) usually happens when there's a problem with the remote services (crash or resource problem). having the WiFi turned off doesn't look like it fits with those criteria. [`onPeersDisconnected`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomStatusUpdateListener#onPeersDisconnected(com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room, java.util.List)) is called when the participants are disconnected from the room.

Determine if the `onP2PConnected` is called when its connected and `onP2PDisconnected` when disconnected (hopefully this can catch WiFi toggling cases) since I think its more appropriate when you're using real-time multiplayer.

You can also read more about it in the [Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#detecting_when_a_player_is_disconnected) section of the documentaiton.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, onP2PDisconnected is not called in this case either.